# How many reparse records are a lot?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ntfs, chkdsk

My computer is acting strangely, slowing and freezing or partially freezing (some applications but not all) fairly often; it has blue screened 3 times in three weeks; I had at least one NTFS error. I am going through possible causes and fixes.

When I chkdsked I got no bad sectors, no bad file records, almost nothing. The only thing I got a lot of was reparse records.

C: (windows disk) using `chkdsk c: /r /scan` I got 54,830 reparse records

```
952506625 KB total disk space.
1780056584 KB in 1786578 files.
    976580 KB in 292305 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
   2462877 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 169010584 KB available on disk.
```

E: using `chkdsk e: /f /r /x /scan /perf` I got 2,467 reparse records (a lot for relatively few files and folders, most of the files big)

```
   2861457 MB total disk space.
   2859364 MB in 6167 files.
     13740 KB in 3204 indexes.
    297495 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
   1832324 KB available on disk.
One Error: The remaining USN block at offset 0x9bf8120 in file 0x29 is less than a page.
```

F: using `chkdsk f: /f /r /x /scan /perf` I got 364 reparse records (not many for more files and folders than e:, many of the files similarly big like e:)

```
   5723036 MB total disk space.
   3585716 MB in 243514 files.
    147480 KB in 25931 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
   1205627 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
   2135998 MB available on disk.
No error, despite the previous NTFS error in windows events
```

So is that a lot of reparse records for c:? Examples I've seen on the internet suggest 40-50 for most people. I know you can have up to 63 per folder, but it still seems like a lot.

Follow up: If it is a lot, perhaps too many, is that an issue? Can anyone suggest a path forward? Do I need to look at what they are, or what is creating them? Can I remove them? Can they reduce computer speed or cause other problems?

Note: Aside from that, I've got some fixing to do. I have DISM issues, which means I can't SFC, etc. etc. But before I deal with that, I have to get the discs fixed or junked...

Comment: Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: @DavidPostill all passed fine, as they did 3 days ago. I thought I had best check again, and now I know about GSmartControl (https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/index.php/Downloads) so thanks for that!